# How to resolve anonymousID command prompt error?

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface, command-prompt, command-line-tool, openvino

I keep encountering this issue(anonymousId) while installing the things required for my OpenVINO project, through command prompt.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.582\deployment_tools\demo>demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.bat
target_precision = FP16
"}},"anonymousId":"laptop-(my laptop name)\ (myUser) was unexpected at this time.

or

C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.582\deployment_tools\inference_engine\demos>build_demos_msvc.bat
"}},"anonymousId":"laptop-(my laptop name)\ (myUser) was unexpected at this time.

or

C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.4.582\deployment_tools\demo>demo_benchmark_app.bat -d CPU
target = CPU
target_precision = FP16
"}},"anonymousId":"laptop-(my laptop name)\ (myUser) was unexpected at this time.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

From OpenVINO perspective, ensure that you have installed [Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 with MSBuild](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) for OpenVINO version 2021.4. Certain [workloads and individual components](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000055251/boards-and-kits/neural-compute-sticks.html) in Microsoft Visual Studio are also required to be installed.

Launch Visual Studio Installer, look for Visual Studio Community 2019, and then choose Modify to download and install those required workloads and individual components.